# Drupal: change background for "Colourise" theme

Tags: drupal, background, themes

I have just installed and applied "Colourise" theme for my website, but background of this theme is too dark. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background color/image is likely located in one of the CSS files for the Colourise theme. Navigate to your theme's folder (sites/all/themes/your_theme_name), and take a look at the style.css file or the css file with your theme's name (likely colourise.css). There should be a background specified in there, likely near the top of the file. Once you make the change, be sure to reset your site's cache at admin/config/development/performance (if you have css compression enabled).

Comment: And another quick comment, a great way to find out where your css elements are coming from is by using a browser such as Firefox, right click on the element you want to see the attributes for, and click "Inspect Element". This will tell you which css file is being called for each element on the page, and which line in that css file is being used. Excellent tool for all skill levels of developers/themers.